# How to add Buttons to a push notification in Android

Tags: java, android

I want my push notification to have two buttons but I couldn't find anywhere how to do so. Can anyone explain how to add buttons to a Push Notification in Android?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify);
    notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    /* blah blah blah  */
}

public void onVerify(View v)
{
    /*
     some code
    */
    if(example){ /* another piece of code */ }
    else{
        String num=data.getString("Phone");
        this.defineNotification(num);
        //Log.i(TAG,"here ");
        Intent i=new Intent(this,VendorDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("Phone",num);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
public void defineNotification(String num)
{
    notification.setContentTitle("Successful");
    notification.setContentText("Hi, I am being displayed now");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Intent i=new Intent(this,OrderTypes.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    notification.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Accept",pi);
    notification.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Decline", pi);
    NotificationCompat.MediaStyle mediaStyle=new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle();
    MediaSessionCompat mediaSession=new MediaSessionCompat(this,TAG);
    mediaStyle.setShowActionsInCompactView(1);
    mediaStyle.setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken());
    notification.setStyle(mediaStyle);


    Intent intent=new Intent(this,VendorDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("Phone",num);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(Verify.this,0,intent,0);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID,notification.build());
    //Log.i(TAG, "coming here in notification");
}
```

I am using MediaSessionCompat instead of MediaSession class. Please check if there is a mistake.

Comment: Android receives push notifications. It does not send them. Also, if you don't know how to create a button and use a button in Android, you basically need to start with a beginner tutorial. There are no shortcuts to learning android programming. You need to learn the fundamentals first. http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: First of all, you need to properly understand the question and then mark it unclear or not useful.

Comment: My question was "How to add Buttons to a Push Notification" not to an Activity.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: I very well know how to add buttons to an activity. But we are here talking about PUSH NOTIFICATIONS

Comment: @SachinParashar Take a look at my answer. I explain how to add buttons to a notification. Basically, we use the `.build` method to edit a notification. If my answer helped, please press the checkmark to accept it. If you need more help, feel free to ask, I am happy to help.

Comment: Sachin, Not all notifications in the notification area are necessarily push notifications. Also, push notifications can show up in Activities (depending on your use case). This is the reason why your question was considered too broad or unclear. This is probably the same reason why googling didn't work for you either. Now you know. There is no harm done. If you want to try to salvage your question, you can always [edit] it to make it clearer and more precise if you wish.

Comment: Did it work? Make sure to accept an answer. If you need more help, feel free to ask. :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want something like this, right?

[image]

For notifications, just use the `.addAction(R.drawable.MYDRAWABLE, "BUTTON", INTENT)` method.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    // Show controls on lock screen even when user hides sensitive content.
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.NotIcon)
//HERE ARE YOUR BUTTONS
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "BUTTON 1", myIntentToButtonOneScreen) // #0
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "BUTTON 2", myIntentToButtonTwoScreen)  // #1
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "BUTTON 3", myIntentToButtonThreeScreen)     // #2
    // Apply the media style template
    .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
    .setShowActionsInCompactView(1)
    .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken())
    .setContentTitle("Example for you")
    .setContentText("Example for you")
    .setLargeIcon(ButtonExampleIcon)
    .build();
```

Take a look at this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Just remember this, in order to customize your notifications, use the `.build` method. That's what we do in the code I gave you. **Let me know if this helped :)**

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want such buttons to be displayed. I'll try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi Ruchir. Thank you so much for your concern. I just now tried to implement it but I am getting an error applying this. I am pasting the error and my code in my question description.

Comment: Thank you Ruchir. It's working fine now. Just deleted that MediaSession code and it's working.

Comment: @SachinParashar Great! Happy to have helped. :-)

Comment: Hey Ruchir can you please help me with this question  :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392765/push-notification-not-proper-android?noredirect=1#comment56531281_34392765

Comment: What kind of `mMediaSession`?

Comment: its good but I want pause and resume button there for downloading video any help would be appreciated